# encryption and decryption in mobile and .net webservices

Tags: .net, iphone, android, web-services, blackberry

i have done implementing mobile app on android,webos,blackberry,iphone.

now i integrate project with .net webservices.

while exchange data i need to encrypt in mobile platform and decrypt in .net webservices

which is best encryption algorithm i tried on internet and got zero.

Please suggest me.if you share any sample code.you save me a lot

Thanks in advance

MaHeSh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you use something NIST approved, like Rijndael or AesManaged encryption in conjunction with a password-based key derivation encryption method (PBKDF2).

Also make sure you use cyphers of at least 256-bit keys (NIST approved for storage and transmission of top secret information). You may also want took into tokenization of your sensitive content with truly random tokens (never cryptographically based tokens).

The implementation of AES is an industry standard and you can find many implementations for each of your client platforms online. The important aspect is for your server to be able to decrypt the encrypted information sent by the clients. Since you are using .NET web services, you can explore the System.Security.Cryptography namespace and in particular the [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) class and the [RinjndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) algorithms.

Here are some implementations on different languages:
[AES for Java and C#](http://oogifu.blogspot.com/2009/01/aes-in-java-and-c.html)
[AES for Objective-C and PHP](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/60926-aes-encryption-objective-c-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the other platforms but blackberry comes out of the box with comprehensive crypto APIS.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/package-summary.html

Comment: i have also same issue i need to support all platforms

Answer (score 0):

Your webservice needs to be hosted on some webserver. Configure it to run on HTTPS rather than HTTP and the communication with your webservice will be encrypted.

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: https will give you privacy of the data flying though the air.  However by itself it doesn't give you authentication.  That is, the client is who it says it is.